# How can I loot the bones from St. Eadric's tomb without being detected?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In the quest **The Guided Hands**, you have to steal three items to join The Travelers. One of these, St. Eadric's remains, is causing me grief.

The problem is that three monks are always staring at the casket containing the bones. I can maneuver such that two of the three are unable to see me, but I can't seem to find a place where the third guy can't see me. I've tried waiting until night, but even at 11pm, 1am, and 4am these guys don't seem to sleep. They seem to just sit around all day waiting for thieves to come steal some bones.
[image]

Is there any way to steal these without being detected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll have to do some testing to pinpoint the exact time, but there is a certain time during the day when that room is only occupied by **one** person. That one person is more focused on sweeping the floor than he is at paying attention to the tomb, making it extremely easy to loot the bones.

**Update**

After doing some extensive testing (read: standing around), I came up with the following results:

- **11:30 AM - 12:04 PM** - Empty
- **12:05 PM -  2:04 PM** - One man praying
- **2:05 PM -  5:00 PM** - Empty

I would do more testing, but I figured a ~5 hour window is ample time to steal everything you'd need and more from St. Eadric's tomb.

Comment: I was lucky enough to have arrived at the correct time of day *completely by accident*, but when I heard the sweeping broom sound I instantly smiled and knew that the mission would be a success. Thanks again for this answer!

Answer (score 5):

At different times of day, the monks do different things.  For instance, when I stole the bones, I stood on the other side of the casket.  The monk on the left was apparently on a break, so he wasn't even there.  Even though I was in full view of the monk on the right, after crouching for about 60 seconds, his awareness started to drop off to zero of its own accord.

The monk in the center was actually the trickiest, as even though I was behind him, I was apparently too close.  After a couple of minutes, he moved out from behind the pulpit and into the room.  His awareness then dropped, and I could loot the bones at my leisure.

Answer (score 5):

Go there around 4PM. There's only one guy sweeping the floor, you can steal the whole place.

Answer (score 4):

If your Alchemy is high enough, you can make a Phasewalk Potion (1 x Cripplespore Cap, 2 x Star Thistles, 2 x Sky Blossoms) It gives you about 10-15 seconds of invisibility which lets you steal anything.

Comment: This is the method I used. Works like a charm, and the ingredients are fairly common as well.

Answer (score 3):

two words smoke bomb :) :) :) :)

Comment: +1 Using smoke bomb you can steal practicaly anything anywhere :D

Answer (score 0):

I had two people in the room and I have the fighter. Hide yourself after the roaming guys turn their back. Hide between the desk and burial. And the eyes will disappear